# P-value with terra regress method

Tags: r, p-value, terra

`terra::regress` takes a SpatRaster with multiple layers and returns a raster with the itercept and slopes for each cell. I use this method to estimate the trend in climatic time series surfaces.

It is possible to also get the P-value of the slope for each cell? And can this be extended to other non-parametric metrics such as Theil-sen and Mann-kendall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example (please always include one).

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
x <- regress(r, 1:nlyr(r))
```

As you point out, that does not return p-values. To get the p-value you would need to write your own function. Something like this:

```
f <- function(Y, X) {
    apply(Y, 1, function(y) {
        m <- lm(y ~ X)
        s <- summary(m)
        as.vector(coefficients(s)[2, c(1,4)])
    })
}

out <- app(r, fun=f, X=1:3, wopt=list(names=c("slope", "pvalue")))
```

This is *much* slower though. I could probably implement that in `regress` but I am unsure how useful that would be. After all, this is not hypothesis testing.  The slope might be informative enough?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Robert. Definitively it is very important to determine if the trend observed is significant and where spatially it is. In my view, I consider p-value assessment a complementary and necessary implementation.